# Odoo v14 Home page removed after server restart

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

Upon server restart the home page designed from front-end in Odoo v14 just got disappear.  Does this happens to anyone else? and what might be the possible reasons? Other than home page everything is on place.

https://www.my-website.com/

Above is the url structure to my home page. But everything removed from that url after server restart.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `db_filter` in your config file matches more than one database. It uses regex to match databases if it matches more than one, it will not be loaded automatically and shows database selector instead.